# How do I use select component to reload page?

Tags: tapestry

I'm building my own PageRow component and I'm trying to figure out how to reload the page after changing the select value from say 10 results to 50. I need to set a query parameter during the refresh too, I thought I could do this using the onChanged event, but that does not work. Any one have any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need to POST the value, you don't actually need to use the select component.

Java

```
@Property private int currentRows;

@Inject private ComponentResources resources;

public Link getEventLink(int rows) {
    Link link =  resources.createEventLink("setRows", rows);
    link.addParameter("foo", "bar");
    return link;
}

Object onSetRows(int rows) {
    ...
    return this;
}
```

TML

```
<select id="rows">
    <t:loop source="[10,20,30,40,50]" value="currentRows">
        <option value="${getEventLink(currentRows)}">${currentRows}</option>
    </t:loop>
</select>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$('#rows').change(function() {
    document.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

You could easily adapt this and use a proper [SelectModel](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/SelectModel.html) and the [select](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Select.html) component.

Comment: Thanks lance, an entirely different way to look at the issue that seems much simpler than the solution I came up with over on the mailing list.

Comment: Sometimes it's easy to forget you still have plain old js and html at your fingertips

Answer (score 0):

On the serverside, @Inject ComponentResources and use createEventLink(...) to generate event urls for each option (10-50).

On the clientside, attach a change listener to the select which sets window.location.href and causes an event url to load.

Comment: Hi Lance, do you happen to have a little sample? I ended up creating a little mixin to handles this which can be found on the mailing list, but I'm always interested in a simpler solution. Thanks.